displaylink-driver not installable with 6.1.0-25-amd64 kernel
Is there a fix I can do on my system? Should I file a bug evdi or another bug tracking of a package?
The last kernel update failed. I had to remove the evdi package. Thereafter the update succeeded. I need evdi for displaylink-driver package to use a docking station. When trying to install displaylink-driver I get below terminal output with a postprocess error having exit code 10. The mentioned make.log is here.
There are not many options for me to get the docking station to work. One bug filed for pop os seems to address this, however, unanswered. It is not the first time I install this package, so one comment in the release note pointing to uefi sec workaround should not bother me. However, tried it, and failed, because I cannot install evdi package. The evdi bug tracker has one issue with post installation return code 10, however, this one is old and refers to older kernel. With the kernkel 6.1.0-24-amd64 kernel it worked before.
# apt install displaylink-driver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  linux-headers-6.1.0-21-common
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  evdi
Suggested packages:
  update-notifier-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  displaylink-driver evdi
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/6,905 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Selecting previously unselected package evdi.
(Reading database ... 268277 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../evdi_1.14.6-100_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking evdi (1.14.6-100) ...
Selecting previously unselected package displaylink-driver.
Preparing to unpack .../displaylink-driver_6.0.0-24_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking displaylink-driver (6.0.0-24) ...
Setting up evdi (1.14.6-100) ...
Sign command: /usr/lib/linux-kbuild-6.1/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub
Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.14.6/source -> /usr/src/evdi-1.14.6

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j16 KERNELRELEASE=6.1.0-25-amd64 all INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/6.1.0-25-amd64/build/include KVERSION=6.1.0-25-amd64 DKMS_BUILD=1...(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.1.0-25-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.14.6/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package evdi (--configure):
 installed evdi package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of displaylink-driver:
 displaylink-driver depends on evdi (>= 1.14.4); however:
  Package evdi is not configured yet.
 displaylink-driver depends on evdi (<< 1.15.0); however:
  Package evdi is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package displaylink-driver (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 evdi
 displaylink-driver
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Regarding Stephen Kitts question:
$ cat synaptics.list 
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/synaptics-repository-keyring.gpg] https://www.synaptics.com/sites/default/files/Ubuntu/ stable main
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/synaptics-repository-keyring.gpg] https://www.synaptics.com/sites/default/files/Ubuntu/ stable non-free


The error comes from an incompatibility with a recent (well, 2022) kernel change:
/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.14.6/build/evdi_fb.c: In function ‘evdifb_create’:
/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.14.6/build/evdi_fb.c:408:23: error: ‘struct drm_fb_helper’ has no member named ‘info’
  408 |         efbdev->helper.info = info;
      |                       ^
/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.14.6/build/evdi_fb.c: In function ‘evdi_fbdev_destroy’:
/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.14.6/build/evdi_fb.c:468:27: error: ‘struct drm_fb_helper’ has no member named ‘info’
  468 |         if (efbdev->helper.info) {
      |                           ^
/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.14.6/build/evdi_fb.c:469:38: error: ‘struct drm_fb_helper’ has no member named ‘info’
  469 |                 info = efbdev->helper.info;
      |                                      ^
/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.14.6/build/evdi_fb.c: In function ‘evdi_fbdev_unplug’:
/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.14.6/build/evdi_fb.c:560:27: error: ‘struct drm_fb_helper’ has no member named ‘info’
  560 |         if (efbdev->helper.info) {
      |                           ^
/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.14.6/build/evdi_fb.c:563:38: error: ‘struct drm_fb_helper’ has no member named ‘info’
  563 |                 info = efbdev->helper.info;
      |                                      ^

The evdi driver you’re trying to build expects the newer info field name, but the kernel you have is older and still uses the fbdev name, and they don’t agree about which kernel version is supposed to do what. This is fixable if you know your way around the kernel, but that might be a big if; you would need to adjust the field handling visible in this evdi change.
Since you’re using Synaptics’ own drivers, you should contact them about this, probably by opening an issue in their issue tracker. They only provide support for Ubuntu, so they might not do anything about it however.
For future reference, since you appear to be running Debian, you might want to use the Debian evdi packages instead of those provided by Synaptics for Ubuntu.
